# Programmatically create Audience in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Is there the possibility to create an Audience in Firebase programmatically?

My users have a custom property with a value. I want to create an audience with user with a certain set of values (each value different for each user).

Via console, I could add a rule for each and every value, so I would like to do this programmatically, but I can't find the relevant documentation.

Is this possible? Don't know whether I should look more into firebase or more into google analytics...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there's no API for manipulating the Firebase console with respect to Analytics.

However, feel free to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with your use case.

Comment: Hi Doug. We're currently planning to implement an achievement system in our app where we hope to tie it to Analytics and Cloud Functions (if a certain user meets the spec via analytics, it would trigger an event for the achievement). But in order to filter the data in analytics, using audience is the only option. We're estimating a minimum of 500 users to at most 2000. Is there currently no other way to filter the analytics data? I could post a question with more details if your prefer. Cheers!